# message consistency test scenario in Kafka

Tags: testing, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, data-consistency

i'm building a POC that contains a Kafka cluster deployed on Kubernetes and three spring boot apps that read from kafka and write to jms and vice versa.

I want to know how data integrity and consistency is ensured for example:
If a producer node failed how the consumer is going to continue reading the message without losing the msg consistency.
Is there a detailed scenario to test this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions) about transactions.

If you are new to Spring; also see [Spring Framework's Transaction Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) which Spring Kafka leverages.

Kafka cannot paritipate in a JTA (XA) transactions so your only option is to consider [Best Efforts 1PC commits](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) via Spring transaction synchronization and deal with the (small) possibility of redeliveries of messages that have previously been processed (after a failure).

Comment: why the need for spring transaction? isn't kafka capable to redeliver the remaining messages(after failure ) from a given offset ?

Comment: Of course it can, but you said `>read from kafka and write to jms and vice versa`. If you want both to be committed or rolled back (best effort 1PC) then you need to synchronize the transactions. Otherwise, one might commit and the other roll back - that still might happen, but the chances are much less.